# gedmo (nested) tree iteration to generate json for Jstree

Tags: json, doctrine-orm, metadata, jstree

I got issues to understand how to export a Gedmo tree as Json to allow it to be put into Jstree (V1.0). Right now, the Jstree is fed by a HTML feed like this :

```
    $htmlTree = $repository->childrenHierarchy(
        null, /* starting from root nodes */
        false, /* true: load all children, false: only direct */
        $options
    );
$options = array(
         'decorate' => true,
         'rootOpen' => '<ul>',
         'rootClose' => '</ul>',
         'childOpen' => '<li>',
         'childClose' => '</li>',
         'nodeDecorator' => function($node) {
            return '<a href='.$this->get('router')->generate('route_to_display_element', array('id' => $node['id'], true)).'">'.$node['name'].'</a>';
         }
    );
```

I use in the Gedmo nested tree implementation in the background with doctrine.
But the thing is that I need to insert an ID attribute into the Jstree for a future drag'n drop functionality, and I did not see any documentation on how to do it with html...

EDIT : 
I can display the tree with a given Json feed, but my iteration procedure to generate it is Flawed :

What it should display (what it displays with the Html feed) : http://nimga.fr/f/a9j56.png

what it actualy displays : http://nimga.fr/f/Uf5BS.png

Any Idea? thanks for reading

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work with [dynatree](https://github.com/mar10/dynatree)

```
  $tree = $repo->childrenHierarchy(
     $taxonomy->getRoot(), 
     false 
  );

 json_encode($tree)
```